# MS Access VBA determine if a SharePoint folder is accessible

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint, vba, unc

Is there a bulletproof way to determine if a SharePoint folder is currently accessible? I am using the UNC path i.e. "\\mycompany\mySharePoint\mySite\myFolder"

I am using FileSystemObject.FolderExists:

```
    If Not fso.FolderExists(uncFolder) Then
    MsgBox "SharePoint folder not found. Cannot connect to folder, or folder does not exist. SharePoint URL required for report: """ & uncFolder & """", vbCritical, "Folder not found"
    GoTo exitHandler
    End If
```

The problem is that this does not work reliably. If the user is connected wirelessly or it is the first time connecting to the folder it may take up to five seconds to connect, authenticate, and open. The FolderExists function can timeout before this and return a false negative.

Is there a reliable way to make sure that the user is able to connect or not? I am using the excellent DoCmd.OutputTo acReport ... acFormatPDF to automate the printing of multiple reports and save them to SharePoint. But I have to make sure that the user is able to connect before I attempt the print and save.

Thanks!!

Comment: Can you put a text file in there, like a one-liner, then read that text file?  That shouldn't time out, and you can trap for a "file doesn't exist" error.

Comment: Hmm, you think that attempting to read a text file wouldn't time out but the FileExist method would?

Comment: You can try adding Connection.CommandTimeout = 0.  Or, you can try what this guy did.  :o)  https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/205819/sharepoint-busy-and-preventing-access-writes

Comment: Thanks. It's sad that there is no answer to his question.

Comment: If you find an answer, put it here so we can finally get one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure, but this might work.. try reading the page with the xmlhttp object, this should wait for the status... set reference to Microsoft XML, or latebind if you prefer..

```
Function TestURL(url As String) As Boolean
 On Error GoTo errhandler
    Dim httpObject As New XMLHTTP
    With httpObject
      .Open "GET", url, False
      .send
      If .ReadyState = 4 And .Status = 200 Then TestURL = True
    End With
   Set httpObject = Nothing
 Exit Function
errhandler:   Debug.Print "TestURL", Err.Description
End Function
```

so you can check, and keep checking if necessary until this function returns true, and sleep in between if you need to before you start exporting...

Comment: Note for others: To late bind change the Dim line above to: "Dim httpObject As Object: Set httpObject= CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

Answer (score 0):

Sharepoint is a layer of HTML forms over the file system, and it is possible to translate the URLs used by Sharepoint into regular Windows File System addresses.

So you need something like this:

```
sFolderPath = TidyFilePath(SharepointFolderURL)
```

And a plain-vanilla call to the Scripting.FileSystemObject  to check the result:

```
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

FSO.FolderExists(sFolderPath)
```

And here's the URL translator...

### VBA URL translator for SharePoint folder paths:

```
Public Function TidyFilePath(strPath As String) As String
' Translate file paths from sharepoint into WinFS paths

strPath = Trim(strPath)

strPath = Replace(strPath, "/", "/")
strPath = Replace(strPath, "%2F", "/")
strPath = Replace(strPath, "/", "\")
strPath = Replace(strPath, "\", "\")
strPath = Replace(strPath, "%5C", "\")
strPath = Replace(strPath, "%20", " ")
strPath = Replace(strPath, " ", " ")
strPath = Replace(strPath, " ", " ")
strPath = Replace(strPath, "%A0", " ")
strPath = Replace(strPath, Chr(160), " ")
strPath = Replace(strPath, "<", "")
strPath = Replace(strPath, ">", "")

If Left(strPath, 7) = "http:\" Then
    strPath = Replace(strPath, "http:\", "", 1)
ElseIf Left(strPath, 8) = "https:\" Then
    strPath = Replace(strPath, "https:\", "", 1)
ElseIf Left(strPath, 6) = "ftp:\" Then
    strPath = Replace(strPath, "ftp:\", "", 1)
ElseIf Left(strPath, 7) = "ftps:\" Then
    strPath = Replace(strPath, "ftps:\", "", 1)
End If

TidyFilePath = strPath

End Function
```

I am certain that someone, somewhere, has published a definitive translator that catches all the HTML entities that are needed in order to make a Windows network path into a valiod URL. It's probably present in a library in System32, if only I knew where to look...

...Any .NET and Ruby developers will be scratching their heads<sup>*</sup> and wondering "*What's all that about? How is this possibly even a question?*" because most modern languages do all this for you at a level you never see or even think about. 






<sub>* By careful choice of words, I have avoided impolite assumptions about the ratio of heads to developer(s). We still haven't figured out where they keep their Enormous Brain(s).</sub>